# Xargs append string to files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have multiple text files in a directory. At the end I want to append a string.

Eg. List of text files in directory.

- a.txt
- b.txt
- c.txt

Command to get their path:

```
find -name "*txt"
```

Then I tried to send

```
'echo "example text" > <filename>
```

So I tried running the following:

```
find -name "*txt" | xargs echo "example_text" >>
```

This command fails.

All I want to is append some text to the files every now and then and since the names of the files keep changing I wanted to use xargs

Comment: `xargs` is an executable. `>>` is a shell directive. Shell directives are processed *before* executables are run.

Comment: Also, `find | xargs` has serious, potentially-security-impacting bugs unless you use `-print0` on the `find` side and `-0` on the xargs side: because xargs does shell-like input parsing when used without `-0` or the GNU extension `-d`, but `find` doesn't write output escaped for that parsing, someone generating malicious filenames can inject arbitrary names.

Comment: If you're looking for more reference material beyond the answers given here, see [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), particularly the sections _Actions in Bulk_ and _Complex Actions_.

Comment: BTW, it's more portable (to non-GNU versions of `find`) to use `find . -name` instead of `find -name`; the ability to leave out the argument telling `find` where to start its search is a nonstandard extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `>>` is a shell directive, if you want it honored via xargs, you need to have xargs start a shell. As [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448123/14122) demonstrates, in many cases a shell glob is enough and you don't need `find` at all; but if you *do* want to use `find`, it can be used correctly either with or without xargs.

---

If you **insist** on using `xargs`, even though it isn't the best tool for the job...

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
  for arg in "$@"; do echo "example_text" >>"$arg"; done
' _
```

Taking `xargs` out, and just using `find` (with `-exec ... {} +` to get the same performance benefits `xargs` would otherwise offer):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c '
  for arg in "$@"; do echo "example_text" >>"$arg"; done
' _ {} +
```

(in both of the above, the `_` substitutes for `$0`, so later arguments become `$1` and later, and are thus iterated over when expanding `"$@"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped. Just out of curiosity I really wanted to make it work via xargs.

Comment: Why not using simply [`tee -a ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72451241/1765658) instead of a `for...` loop?

Comment: @F.Hauri, ...heh, pass all the output files to a single instance of `tee`? That's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` isn't really appropriate here. Maybe a loop over filenames like

```bash
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "example_text" >>"$file"
done
```

Comment: If the OP wants the recursive behavior of `find`, they might want a `shopt -s globstar` and then `for file in **/*.txt`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, I thought about that but their question only seems to show a single directory of files, not a tree.

Answer (score 2):

### Append a string to multiple files, using `tee -a`!

Un*x command `tee` are built for this kind of operation and is a lot quicker!!

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec tee -a <<<'Foo bar baz' {} >/dev/null +
```

But *herestring* will work only if `tee` are executed only once! (thanks to [Charles Duffy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72448037/xargs-append-string-to-files/72451241?noredirect=1#comment127989811_72451241))!

See *pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)* using `globstar` further.

#### And if really you want use `xargs`

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 |
    xargs -0 sh -c 'echo "Foo bar baz"|tee -a "$@" >/dev/null ' _
```

#### But are `find` really required?

If all files are under same directory:

```
tee -a <<<'Foo bar baz' >/dev/null *.txt
```

Else, under [ŧag:bash], using *globstar* ( `shopt -s globstar` ):

```
tee -a <<<'Foo bar baz' >/dev/null **/*.txt
```

Comment: The herestring isn't an argument to `-exec` (instead being something the shell does _before_ starting `find`), so it's only available to read **once**. Thus, the first example will fail when your list of filenames gets so large `find` needs to split it into two separate `execve()` calls. The second one is safe (works correctly for any number of files), and the last ones will explicitly fail instead of silently appending to only the first batch of files, which is at least an improvement over the first.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Correct (I've missed this)!! Answer edited! Anyway, this job have to by done using `tee -a`!

Answer (score 0):

As many pointed out, `xargs` is not appropriate, so you could just simply use find and pipe to `read` in a loop to accomplish what you want easily as shown below.

```
find . -name "*.txt" | while read fname; do echo "example_text">>$fname; done
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly with all possible filenames. To make it more robust, add `-print0` to the `find`, and make it `while IFS= read -r -d '' fname; do echo "example_text">>"$fname"; done` -- quoting the `"$fname"` isn't necessary on all releases of bash, but on some older versions you could get a "bad redirection" error if the name split  or globbed into multiple words. Clearing IFS fixes names that start or end with spaces, and using the `-r` argument to `read` fixes support for names containing backslashes.

Comment: (another class of filenames that can't be handled correctly iterating over `find`'s output without `-print0` is those containing newlines -- to create such a file yourself, try running `touch $'hi\nworld.txt'`)

Answer (score -1):

From the point of view of `bash`, there are three parts in your command:

- Before the pipe character (`find -name "*txt"`)
- Between the pipe and the redirection (`xargs echo "example_text"`)
- After the redirection ( )

`bash` tries to open the output file provided after the redirection but, as you didn't provided anything, `bash` cannot open "nothing" and fails.

To solve your issue, you need to give `xargs` a way to add the line you need to the file (without asking `bash` to redirect the output of `xargs`). A way that should work could be by starting a subshell that performs that operation:

```
find -name "*txt" | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo "example_text" >> {}'
```

Comment: `xargs -I{} bash -c '...{}...'` is a welcome mat to shell injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: What happens if someone creates a file named `$(rm -rf ~).txt`? Or, worse, `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.txt`, so it gets expanded even if you try to patch up your command to surround the `{}` with literal single quotes?

Comment: ...thus, the _secure_ way to pass an argument from `xargs` into `sh` is to pass it out-of-band from the content parsed by the shell as source code -- on the argument list.

Comment: Completely agree. I was just mimicking the behavior that the question was trying to perform. `xargs` was not the right tool in the first place and the base code had several issues. I just pretended to explain why the code was not working as expected.